# Frisby Jasmine html Report

Tags: coffeescript, jasmine, report

Could anyone please tell me how to generate a Report for the test cases I ran through Jasmine. I am using Frisby and Jasmine as frameworks and the test cases are written in coffee Script. I have gone through the JUnit report generated by the Frisby framework but that didn't worked out for me. So, please if anyone have anything on how to create report it would be much appriciated.

Comment: Has @slavo answered the question? If so, accept his answer.

Answer (score 2):

To generate test reports in JUnit format, use --junitreport argument with jasmine-node command.

For example,

Run the command `jasmine-node spec/ --junitreport` will generate a xml file under `/reports`.

The folder where the reports are generated can be changed with `--output` argument. For example,

```
jasmine-node spec/ --junitreport --output reportfolder/new-test-report.xml
```

will generate a test report named as `new-test-report` in `reportfolder` directory.

`--autotest` argument provides automatic execution of specs after each change.
Combining with `--watch` argument can make jasmine-node only re-run tests only if files under specified folders changed.

[source](https://ian_lin.gitbooks.io/javascript-testing/content/chapter3.html)

Comment: Bad folder name with .xml

Answer (score -1):

Install using:

`npm install junit-viewer -g`

Execute the test case using:

`jasmine-node <filename_spec.js> --junitreport`

To generate the report in html format, execute the following command:
`junit-viewer --results=file_or_folder_location --save=file_location.html`

Alternately, to start hosting the report, execute:
`junit-viewer --results=file_or_folder_location --port=port_number`

Comment: How is this different than the last answer?

Comment: @alexanderbirdthe generated report is xml based. To view the report junit-viewer is to be used as described above.

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP was asking about though